# XSLT List View Webpart for Anonymous Users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a public facing SharePoint site, and I have a page I want to add a list to.  The normal behavior of a list is to show the ribbon when selecting an item in the list.  When an anonymous user tries this, they get prompted to authenticate.

Is there a way to disable this behavior for anonymous users, or is it a best practice to not use XSLT List Views where anonymous users need to see list data and use a content query webpart instead?

XSLT List Views with custom xsl is a better way to go, but I'll use a content query webpart instead as an alternative.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds strange to me? All list views are made up of XLV's and I've never seen a problem with lists and anonymous users!? Where do you get the access denied? Use Fiddler to find out which HTTP request causing the problem.

Comment: The authentication prompt happens when I click on an item row.  You know how it selects the checkbox next to it and then opens the ribbon?  It appears to be trying to do that for the anonymous user, as well.

Comment: I found out that by wrapping the core.js file in a security trimmed control in the masterpage, the problem goes away.  However, this seems to cause other issues with JavaScript trying to run on other pages, so I'm not any better off :(